# Preventing user to return to page if save changes

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova

I have a phonegap + angularjs App running. The app basically have this page flow:

Login > Main page with a list > Second page with other list > item details

In the Details page, the user has the hability to save the record. If he saves the record, this page cannot be accessed again when for instance he presses the android back button.

Inside the save method I'm using this to redirect him to the second list again:

```
$location.path('/notifications/' + $scope.placeId);
```

I tried using the replace() after and before redirecting but it doesn't work. The only way I made it work is calling the replace() before going to the details list. The problem is if he presses the back button then it redirects to the 1st list. Very weird

Comment: I'm not used to this way of doing things, hope I can help, when I switch pages in android I usually use startActivity(new Intent()); you can call finish(); right after it and the activity is not gonna show up when you hit back..

Comment: Phonegap applications runs in a webview. All the code is pure javascript so I don't have access to native android code easily.

Comment: Sorry, dont know much about phonegap even tho im working on a webview/javascript app at the moment haha, What I would try to do is make a public bool that can be accessed from anywhere in the code, switch it to true when saving data and then everytime the page loads it check if boolean is at true before continuing... I have no idea if this is possible in your case but maybe it can help a bit

Comment: No that doesn't help. It is strange, I read all the possible docs on angular $location. My understanding is that If I call location.path('path').replace() the url which I'm navigating to will not be saved in the history. But this is not what is happening. It removes the page where I'm redirecting from.

Comment: This is one good headbanger, i'm curious to see how to solve this, good luck on this mate hope you get through